# Asp:Image's Image doesn't change after Image Url has changed

Tags: c#, image, imageurl

I'm creating a WebApplication in visual studio using C# language and I'm new to asp. I'm trying to upload a file to my WebApplication and then show the uploaded file on an `asp:Image` right after the page is uploaded(Right after the upload button is pushed). After I change the `ImageUrl`(`ImageUrl` of the `asp:Image`), the uploaded image will not be shown in the `asp:Image`, but when I refresh the page myself(Pressing `F5`), the image will be shown. I tried to `Redirect` the page again at the end of the upload button's click event, but it didn't work. How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Html:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="imageProfile" /> 

<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="fileUploadProfile" />

<asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/Images/Uplaod.png" ID="imageButtonUpload"
runat="server" OnClick="imageButtonUpload_Click" />
```

Behind code:

```
protected void imageButtonUpload_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    int ID = Convert.ToInt16(labelID.Text);

    if (fileUploadProfile.HasFile)
    {
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Session5_HomeWork;User ID=sa;Password=*************");

        cnn.Open();

        string Command = "Select GuidName from Table_AccountImages where ID = @ID";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Command, cnn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", ID);
        string GuidName = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

        cnn.Close();

        fileUploadProfile.SaveAs(MapPath("~/Profile Images/" + GuidName));
        imageProfile.ImageUrl = "~/Profile Images/" + GuidName;

        Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
    }
}
```

---

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadImage();
    }
}


private void LoadImage()
{
    int ID = Convert.ToInt16(labelID.Text);
     SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Session5_HomeWork;User ID=sa;Password=soroush");

    cnn.Open();

    string command = "Select GuidName from Table_AccountImages Where ID = @ID";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, cnn);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", ID);

    try
    {
        imageProfile.ImageUrl = "~/Profile Images/" + cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        imageProfile.ImageUrl = "~/Profile Images/Default.png";
    }

    cnn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Can you post your onLoad method?

Comment: You set the value and then redirect. The browser will make a new request and the value set will be discarded.

Comment: But when I refresh it will work. And I'm changing the Image the asp:Image is refering to. And as I wrote above, When I don't place the Redirect line, It won't work either.